# Losing headers received from 4.7.2 API Dataset/datatable in dotnet Core 3 API

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core

I have 2 APIs one is my data access proxy for Sybase reports. This is written in Framework 4.7.2 and returns a DTO that contains a property that is a Dataset that is filled by the DbFactory systems or at least a wrapper around them.

The other API is receiving the DTO just fine except that when a datatable is "empty", as in only headers but no rows I receive only the name of the datatable but none of the headers which since I am parsing this into an Excel sheet poses an issue with "Column out of Range" exceptions when attempting to write to the sheets.

I have found only limited information on this and not many solutions. One said that .Net Standard 2+ was supposed to fix the compatibility issues between how Framework and Core serialized datasets.

I need a way to reliably get a datatable/dataset from this API so as to return an Excel Workbook with just the headers if there are no rows.

```
using (connection)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.ChangeDatabase(schema.DatabaseName);
                command.CommandText = $"{schema.Name}.{spName}";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (pList != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add(GetParameter(pList[i].DefaultValue, pList[i].Name, pList[i].BaseParameter?.DbTypeName));
                    }
                }
                command.Fill(ds);

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                {
                    ds.Tables[i].TableName = $"{spName}{i + 1}";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorLogger.Error($"{e.Message}, {e.InnerException} with a trace of {e.StackTrace}", e);
                if(e.Source.Contains("SQL Anywhere .NET Data Provider"))
                    throw new Exception($"An error has occurred that has to do with the Stored Procedure and needs correcting at that level: {e.Message}");
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

And I just do a standard deserialization on the Core side like this:

```
report = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ResponseObject>();
```

[image: This is what I get from the 4.7.2 API...]

[image: This is what I have when I receive the DTO from the 4.7.2 API inside Core 3]

UPDATE:
So it would appear that in the 4.7.2 API the object contains the metadata in the datatable and shows the headers as well, but when I get back the Postman hit it simply has a named array.

```
"Table": {
        "ReportHighRiskEntityAccounts1": []
    },
```

How do I ensure that the Datatable metadata gets serialized upon transmission from 4.7.2 API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had to actually force a row into the empty DataTable in order for the serialization to pick up that there was structure in this case.

I am hoping there is something else out there that is a more elegant solution for later implementation but that is what I have for now.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    clone.Rows.Add("No data for the parameters provided.");
}
```